# How to sort a list based on the output of numpy's argsort function

Tags: python, list, sorting, numpy

I have a list like this:

```
 myList = [10,30,40,20,50]
```

Now I use `numpy's argsort` function to get the indices for the sorted list:

```
import numpy as np
so = np.argsort(myList)
```

which gives me the output:

```
array([0, 3, 1, 2, 4])
```

When I want to sort an array using `so` it works fine:

```
myArray = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
myArray[so]
array([1, 4, 2, 3, 5])
```

But when I apply it to another list, it does not work but throws an error

```
myList2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
myList2[so]
```

> TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an
>   index

How can I now use `so` to sort another list without using a for-loop and without converting this list to an array first?

Comment: It is already a nice example to see how to sort a second list based on the first one. As it is done with multiple columns and sort the table by first column, but only interested in the ordered second one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. You have to convert it to an array then back.

```
myListSorted = list(np.array(myList)[so])
```

Edit: I ran some benchmarks comparing the NumPy way to the list comprehension. NumPy is ~27x faster

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> import numpy as np

>>> myList = list(np.random.rand(100))
>>> so = np.argsort(myList) #converts list to NumPy internally
>>> timeit(lambda: [myList[i] for i in so])
12.29590070003178

>>> myArray = np.random.rand(100)
>>> so = np.argsort(myArray)
>>> timeit(lambda: myArray[so]) 
0.42915570305194706
```

Comment: Yes, converting it to an array first would be an option but that is something I wanted to avoid. But thanks for your answer anyway; I upvoted it.

Comment: You **can**, as `Anand S Kumar` explained. But otherwise, great answer

Comment: @goncalopp I assumed list comprehensions were covered under for loops.

Comment: @Cleb Using the NumPy method is ~28x faster than list comprehensions. Why do you want to avoid using it?

>>> timeit(lambda: [l[i] for i in o])
12.29590070003178

>>> timeit(lambda: a[o])
0.42915570305194706

Comment: @Cleb In case you end up using this, to get this speed I had to change one more thing as well:  so = np.argsort(myList) converts the list to a numpy array internally. Converting it back and forth twice is inefficient, so I kept a separate variable myArray.

Comment: @rohanp: Could you add this to your answer, please?!

Comment: @rohanp: What is timeit(lambda: a[o])? Neither 'a' nor 'o' are defined. Should this be 'myArray' and 'so'?

Answer (score 5):

`myList2` is a normal python list, and it does not support that kind of indexing.

You would either need to convert that to a `numpy.array` , Example -

```
In [8]: np.array(myList2)[so]
Out[8]: array([1, 4, 2, 3, 5])
```

Or you can use list comprehension -

```
In [7]: [myList2[i] for i in so]
Out[7]: [1, 4, 2, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Yes, converting it to an array first would be an option but that is something I wanted to avoid. Seems I will go for the list comprehension then... I upvoted it and accept it later on if nothing better shows up.

Comment: @Cleb I think a list comprehension is as good as you possibly can get. Unless you favor the more functional-style `map(myList2.__getitem__, so)`, which looks terrible in python

Comment: @goncalopp: Yes, I guess I go with it. I just like slicing, using indices etc so I was wondering whether there is a way to do it.